# Oracle Apex 5.1 apex_item.checkbox2 always displays as a Text String

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I was trying to show checkbox data stored in a list format in a report.  For instance, 23:45:56 is stored in the database and represents 3 items that were checked and then saved from a form.  I was not able to get that to work and since have tried to get a basic example to work.

Now I am trying to create a report using the following query:

```
select apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx => 1, p_value => allocation_type_id) AS "Select" 
from allocation_type_l
```

What is rendered amounts to a string:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="129" />
```

There is never an option to change the column type to a "checkbox".  Any suggestions about what I could be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for not asking "Why would you ever want to do such a thing?"

Comment: Also see this for further detail http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2017/01/escape-special-characters-apex-demo.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to that column's property palette (on the right of the screen), scroll down and set **Escape special characters** property to "No".